# Play ParseFile Video with Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie Unity

Tags: android, video, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

I am a newbie in Unity3d and Parse.com.
I want to play online video that I store in Parse.com. However when I get an AbsoluteUri of parse file for play, It open video and just play for 1s then it auto close. What thing I did wrong ? see the code below

```
public void queryBundleWithName(){

    var query = ParseObject.GetQuery ("AssetBundle").
        WhereEqualTo("name", "Board");

    query.FirstAsync().ContinueWith(t =>{
        ParseObject relatedObjects = t.Result;
        string name = relatedObjects.Get<string>("name");
        //isFinish = true;

        urlVideo = relatedObjects.Get<ParseFile>("video").Url.AbsoluteUri;
        textResult.text =  urlVideo;

        Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
        Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie (urlVideo, Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.CancelOnInput, FullScreenMovieScalingMode.AspectFill);
    });
}
```

Thank for your help.